# Let $f_n$ sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ uniformly on $(a,b)$. Show $f_n\mapsto f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n$ sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ uniformly on $(a,b)$. Show that $f_n\mapsto f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$.

I would like to know how to continue my proof, please.

First of all, as $f_n$ are continuous on closed interval, this sequence is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. By definition we have: $\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists \delta_1>0 \ \forall x,y \in [a,b]$: $|x-y|<\delta_1 \implies|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\epsilon$

As $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $(a,b)$, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$. Moreover, the uniform continuity of $f$ on $(a,b)$ implies that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$ exist. So by extension by continuity we have that $f$ is uniofmrly continuous on $[a,b]$: $\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists \delta_2>0 \ \forall x,y \in [a,b]$: $|x-y|<\delta_2 \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

We would like to show the following: $\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists N \ \forall n\ge N \ \forall x \in [a,b]$: $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

How can i conclude with all the hypothesises that I've done until now?

**Edit**: Probably I could have tried to prove by absurd and work with sequence $x_n$ which is bounded so by Bolzano-Weierstrass there is a converging sub-sequence(So cauchy) then use the uniform continuity to get a contradiction

Comment: "First of all, as $f_{n}$ are continuous on closed interval, this sequence is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$."  Considering the question, this seems like a logical jump to me.  How confident are you in your proof?

Comment: @Peter Morfe if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then it is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, no? Probably, to be more rigorous, i should have taken each $\delta_i$ of every function, and take it's min?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the uniform Cauchy criterion, there exists $N(\epsilon)$ such that for all $m > n \geqslant  N(\epsilon)$ and all $x \in (a,b)$, we have $|f_m(x) - f_n(x) | < \epsilon$.

By continuity, this implies that $|f_m(a) - f_n(a)| = \lim_{x \to a+}|f_m(x) - f_n(x)| \leqslant \epsilon$, and similarly as $x \to b-$.

Comment: Is there the possibilty to continue my proof, withour using Cauchy criterion?

Comment: Basically the same idea, but my proof circumvents proving that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon $ for all $n \geqslant N(\epsilon)$ and $x \in (a,b)$.  Now take limits as $x \to a+$ and $x \to b-$.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you! But before taking these limits, I have to prove that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, right? (i.e pass by uniform continuity on $(a,b)$ then conclude by extension)

Comment: @Daniil: You stated but did not prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$.   How would you do that?

Comment: As $f_n$ are uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, it is as well on $(a,b)$. As $f_n\to f$ uniofrmly on $(a,b)$, it implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$, right? To proof that, it is a "straightforward definition chasing". Or it is wrong?

Comment: You would use the triangle inequality: $|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant |f(x) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| + |f_n(y) - f(y)|$. The you apply the uniform convergence and uniform continuity of $f_n$. Next you use the fact that $f$ can be extended continuously. This is a lot of work not shown.  So that leads me back to why would you not prove this in 2 lines?  Apparently my answer does not appear to be helpful to you.

Comment: But how can i extend $f$ by continuity without knowing that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$(same for $b$) exists? And to ensure it's existence, i have to pass by the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$. Edit: Oh, your inequality showing that $f$ is uniformly cont. on $(a,b)$, i missed that, sorry

Comment: Yes, I'm agree that it is too much work for nothing (and all the hypothesise I've put, it has to be shown). But, I didn't see the Cauchy criterion for sequences of functions(even if it is not something difficult), so that is why I don't really want to use it. I would like to use results I've seen till now..

Comment: If a function is uniformly continuous on the open interval $(a,b)$ then it can be extended continuously to the closed interval. This has a straightforward but lengthy proof, which by the way uses Cauchy criterion as you have to produce the existence of a limit as $x \to a,b$ out of thin air.

Comment: Yes, to show that I have to consider a sequence converging to $a$ (and $b$)

Comment: It kind of makes sense to ask another question now.

Comment: So my approach works without Cauchy but passing by uniform continuity of $f$ on $(a,b)$ (Of course i have to proof all of those results)?

Comment: Knowing that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ it works. Again you have the problem of proving that step.  You have to take any sequence $x_n \to a$ and show that $(f(x_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence and, hence, has a limit $L = \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)$.  Then you have to show that $L$ is independent of the choice for $(x_n)$.  Now you have $f(a) := L$.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry for bothering, but I just want to be sure about my approach. Once i prove that 
 $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ and that it implies that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and  $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$ exist $\implies$ we can extend $f(x)$ on $a$ and $b$ $\implies$ $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, is the following correct? $|f_n(a)-f(a)|= \lim_{x\to a^+}|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ (by uniform convergence on $(a,b)$), then I do the same for $b^-$. So I can conclude that the convergence is uniform on $[a,b]$

Comment: No problem.  Yes -- we know that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ and $n \geqslant N$ where $N$ does not depend on $x$.  We know that $f_n(x) \to f_n(a)$ and now $f(x) \to f(a)$ as $x \to a+$.  Thus $|f_n(a) - f(a)| = \lim_{x \to a+}|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leqslant \epsilon$.  Notice that strict inequality $< \epsilon$ can be lost when taking a limit, but that is not important. Showing the same thing as $x \to b-$, we now satify the requirement for uniform convergence on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much for bearing me and for your answers! Everything is clear now!